# Using Jython to print html title?

Tags: html, jython

In jython, is there a way to create a function that takes in a url (html) as a parameter, and returns the title of the url (whatever's in between the `<title>` and `</title>`)?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is!

At first download page you want to analyse. You can do it with `urllib2` module. Read its documentation and at the bottom you will find examples of how to read page content.

When you have page content you must locate title in it. You can do it in many ways. There are modules for parsing HTML but for such simple task you can use regular expression (module `re`) or even string functions (`find()` method).

Be aware that HTML tags are case sensitive, so if you are going to use `find()` method to locate start and end of the title you may also need `lower()` method and copy of original page.